Master/Slave non persistent ActiveMQ Classic configuration
I am trying to setup two ActiveMQ Classic brokers used as communication channel for several microservices.
I would like to:

Have the brokers on two different machines so that the two brokers are in failover, where upon switching off one of the machines the other acquires a lock and becomes the master.
Don't have to worry about disk usage that comes with persistent messages.

In short I want to have redundant brokers with no persistence, so I can, for example, switch off one node for mainteinance and have the other accept connections.
It seems there is not way to achieve this as of 5.18.3, since a broker configured to use Kahadb as  Shared File System Master Slave but with persistent="false" attribute active
produces this log:
WARN | persistent="false", ignoring configured persistenceAdapter: KahaDBPersistenceAdapter

and the brokers effectively ignore the lock file check (they both go active).
The two relavant bits of configuration in settings.xml are:
...
<broker persistent="false" xmlns="http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core" brokerName="localhost" dataDirectory="${activemq.data}">
...
   <persistenceAdapter>
      <kahaDB directory="/mnt/SHARED_AMQ" lockKeepAlivePeriod="1000">
         <locker>
            <shared-file-locker lockAcquireSleepInterval="1000"/>
         </locker>
      </kahaDB>
   </persistenceAdapter>
...

Mind that I achieved the working redundant configuration with persistence, removing the persistent="false".

Reading the definition of persistance I think I intitially misunderstood and the memory affected is only the secondary one (disk) "The main difference is that if you are using persistent delivery, messages are persisted to disk/database so that they will survive a broker restart. When using non-persistent delivery, if you kill a broker then you will lose all in-transit messages."
I will edit my question to amend.

To achieve your desired solution, you cannot disable persistence altogether (pesistent="false" should not be used).
Instead, use the persistence solely for the primary/failover lock (formerly known as master/slave). Clients are responsible for setting the persistence flag, so you will still have non-persistent behavior as desired. Optionally, you can force all messages to be non-persistent using the plugin.
As a bonus, when you have kahadb enabled, if you start to run out of memory, ActiveMQ will swap non-persistent messages to disk using the temporary store. This allows the broker to handle more non-persistent messages than it has available memory.
Edit: Please upgrade your ActiveMQ brokers to current releases 6.x or 5.18.x!

Hi Matt, thanks for the answer! I am actually using a 5.18.3 broker, I will edit my question to fix the version I put there, thanks for the heads up.
I will explore your solution and possibly comment with the configuration that works for me.

Thanks to the direction given by @Matt I managed to wing togheter an xml for AMQ configuration that works for me.
<beans
  xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
  http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core/activemq-core.xsd">
    <bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <property name="locations">
            <value>file:${activemq.conf}/credentials.properties</value>
        </property>
    </bean>
    <broker xmlns="http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core" brokerName="localhost" dataDirectory="${activemq.data}">
            <plugins>
                <forcePersistencyModeBrokerPlugin></forcePersistencyModeBrokerPlugin>
             </plugins>
        <destinationPolicy>
            <policyMap>
              <policyEntries>
                <policyEntry queue="ActiveMQ.DLQ">
                    <deadLetterStrategy>
                      <sharedDeadLetterStrategy expiration="1000"/>
                    </deadLetterStrategy>
                  </policyEntry>
                <policyEntry topic=">" >
                  <pendingMessageLimitStrategy>
                    <constantPendingMessageLimitStrategy limit="1000"/>
                  </pendingMessageLimitStrategy>
                </policyEntry>
              </policyEntries>
            </policyMap>
        </destinationPolicy>
        <managementContext>
            <managementContext createConnector="false"/>
        </managementContext>
        <persistenceAdapter>
                <kahaDB directory="/mnt/SHARED_AMQ" lockKeepAlivePeriod="1000">
                        <locker>
                                <shared-file-locker lockAcquireSleepInterval="1000"/>
                        </locker>
                </kahaDB>
        </persistenceAdapter>
          <systemUsage>
            <systemUsage>
                <memoryUsage>
                    <memoryUsage percentOfJvmHeap="70" />
                </memoryUsage>
                <storeUsage>
                    <storeUsage limit="10 gb"/>
                </storeUsage>
                <tempUsage>
                    <tempUsage limit="10 gb"/>
                </tempUsage>
            </systemUsage>
        </systemUsage>
        <transportConnectors>
            <transportConnector name="openwire" uri="tcp://0.0.0.0:61616?maximumConnections=1000&amp;wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600"/>
            <transportConnector name="amqp" uri="amqp://0.0.0.0:5672?maximumConnections=1000&amp;wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600"/>
            <transportConnector name="stomp" uri="stomp://0.0.0.0:61613?maximumConnections=1000&amp;wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600"/>
            <transportConnector name="mqtt" uri="mqtt://0.0.0.0:1883?maximumConnections=1000&amp;wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600"/>
            <transportConnector name="ws" uri="ws://0.0.0.0:61614?maximumConnections=1000&amp;wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600"/>
        </transportConnectors>
        <shutdownHooks>
            <bean xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" class="org.apache.activemq.hooks.SpringContextHook" />
        </shutdownHooks>
    </broker>
    <import resource="jetty.xml"/>
</beans>

